# Merging all tiles from one directory using GDAL

Tags: gdal, mosaic, osgeo4w, shell

I would like to use GDAL (under Windows; OSGeo4W Shell) to merge all GeoTIFFs from one directory into a new GeoTIFF. I have tried to address them by writing `c:\data\....\*.tif` which however does not seem to work, using the Windows environment.

I am looking for the most practicable way to perform this operation; if possible completely within the OSGeo4W Shell. Addressing every single mosaic part name 'by hand' in the Shell is not an option.

Comment: Please write the full command you used and provide more details about the results obtained using that command.

Comment: ...also quote the error message

Comment: What tool? [gdal_merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)?

Comment: Very old but the documentation shows how to do this on both linux and Windows machines: https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html#passing-a-large-list-of-files-to-gdal-merge

Answer (score 37):

You could create a virtual mosaic from all Tiff files:

```
gdalbuildvrt mosaic.vrt c:\data\....\*.tif
```

and convert it afterwards:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -co "PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR" -co "TILED=YES" mosaic.vrt mosaic.tif
```

Keep an eye on all the GDAL creation parameters to compress your mosaic and use gdaladdo to add overviews.

More info here: [GeoTiff Compression for Dummies - Paul Ramsey](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/geotiff-compression-for-dummies.html)

Comment: Just a small hint: increasing GDAL_CACHEMAX could bring a performance boost.

On Windows: set GDAL_CACHE_MAX=128

or gdal_translate --config GDAL_CACHE_MAX 128 -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" ...

Comment: Does the same command work for Linux?

Comment: `E:\>gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff output.vrt mosaic10.tif
Input file size is 2818, 1267
0Warning 6: GDAL_RASTERIO_RESAMPLING = {nearest} not supported
Warning 6: GDAL_RASTERIO_RESAMPLING = {nearest} not supported
ERROR 4: E:\GHRC\20200203\202003401_20200203040951_20200203104318_20200203115400_frames\FRAME0001.tif: No such file or directory` I am getting error like this. How to fix it?

Comment: @wondim the same command works across all platforms

Comment: Here is how the same thing can be done in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66663626/2842067

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use python, then you can use wildcards to select files with the glob module, and then you can execute the command with os.system.

```
import glob
import os

file_list = glob.glob("c:\data\....\*.tif")

files_string = " ".join(file_list)

command = "gdal_merge.py -o output.tif -of gtiff " + files_string

os.system(command)
```

Comment: Important to point out gdal_merge loads all tiffs in memory, so probably wouldn't be a great choice while working with big rasters