# How to merge all raster files in a folder using gdal_merge?

Tags: gdal, mosaic, osgeo4w, gdal-merge, powershell

I have DEMs in a folder like this
[image]

If I run `gdal_merge -o out.tif *.hgt`, it says

> ERROR 4: `/*.hgt' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.

A similar thread asked this but the solution was to make a virtual file first and convert it to a .tif file. [Merging all tiles from one directory using GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/230553/146811)

Another similar thread https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2783#no1

Comment: You must make a input file list (file1.tif file2.tif file3.tif...). You can select your tools for that but there is a solution for building the file list with Python in  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230553/merging-all-tiles-from-one-directory-using-gdal. However, I would also recommend to use gdalbuildvrt.

Comment: Yes, typing the files manually is the workaround. But I'd like to use a wildcard since there might be a case that there are just too many raster files for me to type. I added in my post a similar thread which says the GDAL Python tools do not support wildcards.

Comment: I did not say that you must make the list manually, use your favorite scripting language instead. But why not to use `gdalbuildvrt output.vrt *.hgt` instead? All 13 years old issues are not valid any more but the one that you found may be.