# Converting Tile Folder to GeoTIFF using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, mbtiles

I have a folder full of tiles, and I'd like to convert them into a single GeoTIFF file.

The folder structure looks like this:

```
10 //the zoom
    554 //y
        860.jpg //x
        861.jpg
        862.jpg
```

Not quite sure what that structure is called Mapbox Tiles? XYZ? Slippy tiles?

Either way, I tried the following:

```
gdal_translate.exe -if MBTiles -of GTiff "C:\maps\tiles" "C:\maps\output.tiff"
```

But it returns:

> ERROR 4: "C:\maps\tiles": Permission denied

Does GDAL support conversion of folders full of tiles?

Comment: does your user have permission to that directory?

Comment: I was under the impression that the MBTiles format was sqlite DB based not file based (see GDAL [MBTiles driver doc](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/mbtiles.html) and the [MBTiles specification](https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-spec))

Comment: If your folder is full of georeferenced Tiff files, you could create a virtual raster (VRT) first and translate it to a single GeoTIFF file afterwards. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230553/merging-all-tiles-from-one-directory-using-gdal/230588#230588 for more info.

Comment: If your tiles are not georeferenced, you need to create World files for each of them at first step.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Ian - yes they have permission.

Comment: @user2856 I updated the question with the folder structure.

Comment: @Christoph thanks, that sounds good. The tiles are plain jpgs, but their place in the folder structure tells you their coords, in accordance with this equation: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#C.23_2

Comment: Guess you need something like gdal2tiles.py, but the other way round. Maybe you could look into MapProxy (https://mapproxy.org). There you could configure your tile directory as file cache and try to reproduce the Tile Map Service.

Comment: The GDAL driver that supports using a x/y/z folder as source is WMS driver with the TMS minidriver https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html#tms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, by saving it in a text file and changing the extension to .bat:

```
set pathin=F:\mydirectoryname\In
set pathout=F:\mydirectoryname\Out
set filename=merged_file

gdalbuildvrt -allow_projection_difference index.vrt %pathin%\*.tif 
gdal_translate index.vrt %pathout%\%filename%.tif -tr 0.3 0.3 -co COMPRESS=LZW -co BIGTIFF=YES -a_nodata 0
```

Then simply run the bat file. This has the cool bonus of resampling if needed. I do this through the OSGeo4W shell that comes with QGIS - there you already have the GDAL library.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download GDAL. Windows binaries can be found [here](https://apps.nationalmap.gov/raster-conversion/gdal-installation-and-setup-guide.html).
2. Create a file called tiles.xml, which describes your folder structure. For example:

   ```
   <GDAL_WMS>
       <Service name="TMS">
           <ServerUrl>file://C:/map data/Sydney/${z}/${y}/${x}.jpg</ServerUrl>
           <!--<ServerUrl>http://localhost:5000/map%20data/Sydney/${z}/${y}/${x}.jpg</ServerUrl>-->

           <Layer>basic</Layer>
           <Format>jpg</Format>
       </Service>

       <DataWindow>
           <TileLevel>12</TileLevel>
           <TileY>-360</TileY>
           <YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
       </DataWindow>

       <BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
       <BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
       <BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
       <ZeroBlockHttpCodes>404</ZeroBlockHttpCodes>
       <MaxConnections>1</MaxConnections>
   </GDAL_WMS>
   ```
3. Open a console window and set up an environment variable:

   ```
   set PROJ_LIB="C:\Portable\gdal\release-1928-x64-gdal-3-3-3-mapserver-7-6-4\bin\proj7\share"
   ```
4. Run the following commands:

   ```
   cd "C:\Portable\gdal\release-1928-x64-gdal-3-3-3-mapserver-7-6-4\bin\gdal\apps\"

   gdal_translate.exe -of GTiff "C:\map data\Sydney\tiles.xml" "C:\map data\sydney.tiff" -projwin 151.033285 -33.743981 151.300567 -33.957583
   ```

Information about `gdal_translate.exe` can be found [here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html).

Information about the WMS/TMS xml file can be found [here](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html).